# Problem to get current user id in laravel model?

Tags: laravel

Model function :

```
class Cart extends Model
{

   public static function cart()
   {
     $id = \Auth::user()->id;
     $count = Cart::where('user_id' , $id)->sum('quantity');
     return $count;
   }
}
```

But it shows **Trying to get property 'id' of non-object** at view page. Please help me how to solve this?

Comment: try auth()->user()->id

Comment: not work bro...

Comment: in __construct  apply  middleware  auth public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

Comment: Auth::id() ? try that

Answer (score 1):

You can use Auth::User()->id; to get current user id.

Answer (score 0):

**You have multiple options:**

```
1) use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

   Auth::user()->id;

2) auth()->user()->id;

3) if (Auth::check()) 
   {
     //check if a user is logged in, now get the id
      Auth::user()->id
   }

4) Auth::id();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
pass `$userId` rather then `auth()`
it's not good practice to call auth function inside model
because auth is applyed on controller so from controller you can send auth  user id

model will also work but good practice is keep auth inside your controller

```php
class Cart extends Model
{

   public static function cart($userId)
   {
     $count = Cart::where('user_id' , $userId)->sum('quantity');
     return $count;
   }
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error not depends to :

> ```
>  $id = \Auth::user()->id;
> ```

Its ok.
Your problem is ther you call record of Cart in this line:

> ```
>  $count = Cart::where('user_id' , $id)->sum('quantity');
> ```

Use dd($id) and dd($count) to see that probably there is no Cart record with that feature in database. :)